# Mass-fix broken links from old usages of autocard functionality

Tags: discussion, status-completed, mtg-autocard

We have a nice autocard feature, which lets you easily link to Magic: The Gathering cards like [Lightning Bolt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Bolt) with the following syntax:

```
[mtg:Lightning Bolt]
```

When this feature was first introduced, the resulting link was different, e.g. `http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=Lightning%20Bolt` instead of `https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Bolt`. However, those links don't work anymore and they're quite widespread: [this query](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22www.wizards.com%2Fmagic%2Fautocard.asp%22) lists all 1,786 of them.

I was planning to ask the Community Managers if they can assist; it looks very much like repairing broken links for which they have a [script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370325/295232) that can do so *without bumping posts*. Any thoughts from your side before I reach out to them?

Comment: Yes, mass fixing, this is beyond annoying!

Comment: Hey y'all, just letting you know this is on my list. It takes a dev to run the appropriate changes (I've reviewed them and it looks quite possible), but that probably won't happen until early January because of the holidays.

Comment: @Slate thanks for the response - considering these links are broken since (probably) a couple of years already, a few weeks delay won't be a problem :)

Comment: @slate are you aware of this: [Switch Magic autocard over to a different search engine, Scryfall](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/switch-magic-autocard-over-to-a-different-search-engine-scryfall)

Comment: @Pureferret Thanks, hadn't seen that. I'll ask if it's possible, but it probably won't be something we can do with the standard link replacer because of the particle. Will follow up soon.

Comment: I don't think switching over to Scryfall is necessary or even particularly desired here. That question was essentially an alternative to [this other suggestion](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/can-the-autocard-feature-be-improved-again), which was recently implemented.

Comment: @murgatroid99 my impression was, only based on my memory when I first saw them, was that scryfall was preferred, but the stopgap you linked to would do for now. I'll have to go back and re-read when I have the chance

Comment: Actually, looking at it again, the Scryfall suggestion was actually older than the other one I linked. Both of those suggestions were made to address the same problem: for a few reasons, some cards could not be linked properly. That problem has been addressed by the implementation of the post I linked, so we don't need another change to solve it again.

Comment: @murgatroid99 the feature request doesn't just fix bugs, but adds language support and uses a better maintained and more reliable service - meaning fewer future bugs that we'd need SO Devs to fix. Gather goes down (or at least used to) when new cards are added, whereas Scryfall doesn't. There's lots more to using scryfall than just fixing a few cards.

Comment: This post is being discussed [elsewhere on meta](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2076/2133).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These links should now be fixed. These actually step outside the standard link replacer, because of some implementation details in the autocard functionality works.

So, there may be a few stragglers floating around with broken links. *Any* edit to those posts should fix the issue, even if the edit does not change the autocard link itself. Bar those few posts, the links should now be working again.

Shout if y'all spot an egregious number of nonworking links.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated 8 posts with a manual link to the old URL, and [this query](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22www.wizards.com%2Fmagic%2Fautocard.asp%22) now returns 0 results.

Comment: @Glorfindel Perfect! By memory, that checks out. :)

Comment: That's awesome thanks!

Answer (score 6):

That would be a good idea! I have been manually fixing them as I run across them and mass fixing them without bumps would be better.