# Do we still want to switch to using Scryfall as the autocard service?

Tags: feature-request, magic-the-gathering, mtg-autocard

This [2017 post](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/switch-magic-autocard-over-to-a-different-search-engine-scryfall) makes some compelling arguments for switching over to [Scryfall](https://scryfall.com/).

But it's 4 years (and a change) out of date.

Before we [commit to mass-fixing](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2068/2133) the currentlybroken gatherer links, can we double check that:

a) this is a super-simple no cost batch update; or
b) we wouldn't rather switch search engine to Scryfall at the same time

If the mass-fix is a simple low-cost low-risk batch update, there should be no reason to wait. If it's more complicated/costly than we realise then I'd rather wait.

Comment: I think the mass-fix request is not relevant here. That request is just to update old links with the current link rendering template to fix broken links. It's something that we want on a shorter timeframe than how long we should take to decide whether to switch to a different site for card links.

Comment: It should be noted that a big fix was done to the auto card feature in the last year and it should have fixed most of the issues we had in the past. Just need the mass update to fix the older links. [Can the Autocard feature be improved (again)?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/can-the-autocard-feature-be-improved-again)

Comment: @murgatroid99 I think if we can come to a conclusion before the mass-fix it's very relevant. There's no point wasting effort on the mass fix if we're going to switch over in the near future.

Comment: The mass-fix is a simple batch update and it should happen ASAP. If we add in implementing and testing a rendering change, it will take longer, which is undesirable.

Comment: @murgatroid99 if it's that simple then it shouldn't matter, but I'm happy to hear either way from the devs

Answer (score 2):

**In my opinion, we should not switch to Scryfall.**

The main thing Gatherer has going for it that Scryfall can never match is Rule 108.1 of the Magic: the Gathering Comprehensive Rulebook:

> Use the Oracle card reference when determining a card’s wording. A card’s Oracle text can be found using the Gatherer card database at Gatherer.Wizards.com.

Gatherer is the official source of truth for card text, and we should respect that by linking to Gatherer by default when providing card text in questions and answers.

In addition, in the time since the linked Scryfall suggestion was posted, a different [suggestion to improve Gatherer links](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/can-the-autocard-feature-be-improved-again) was implemented. That change fixes most if not all of the problems originally referenced as reasons to switch to Scryfall. As a result, our Gatherer links are good enough now that we should not switch and lose the value of linking to the official source of truth.