# Can anyone qualified look into the [mtg:] tag?

Tags: support, magic-the-gathering, mtg-autocard

In [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/42378/who-decides-which-of-the-or-effects-is-applied), the "mtg:Searing Spear" ([Searing Spear](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSearing%20Spear%5d)) doesn't work for me, and it sometimes doesn't for other cards either. It gets me to Gatherer, but it can't find any result, despite correct spelling. It can't be about multiple matches either, because e.g. [Lightning](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%5d) also works. Most other cards work fine, including card names with multiple words, such as [March of the Machines](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarch%20of%20the%20Machines%5d). I tried with Chrome and Edge, so it's probably not about the browser. Right now I suspect Gatherer as it's been wonky in the recent past, but just to be sure, is there anything on our end that can be done about it?

For example, could someone try to change the url to

http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=+[searing]+[spear]

i.e. to put every word in its separate pair of brackets, preceded by the + sign?

Comment: Are you using a language other than English for your device or for Gatherer?

Comment: Searing Spear and Searing Spear Askari are both possible results as well as plenty of other cards with one of the two words which I would guess is the problem in this case and not language.

Comment: I use english. As I said, I suspect Gatherer is at fault. If the search result is a substring of at least one other card, as is the case here, that might be the problem. But again, if we change the search string, we might work around the problem.

Comment: Can you at least tell me if you can repro the issue?

Comment: I got the same issue which is why I made the comment.

Comment: This has been known to be partially broken for quite a while, and the issue is just that it takes dev time to fix it. The most recent proposed fix: https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1652/409

Comment: Yep, I can repro this (now that I turned off a userscript that was fixing it, whoops). There is also this proposal which sticks with Gatherer and works perfectly: https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/can-the-autocard-feature-be-improved-again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Magic card auto link feature be improved?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1152/can-the-magic-card-auto-link-feature-be-improved)